# duplication of terra rasters and side effects

Tags: duplicates, raster, side-effects, terra

When modifying some of the attributes of a duplicated `SpatRaster`, the original is also modified:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncol=2, nrow=2, vals=c(5.3, 7.1, 3, 1.2))
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 2, 2, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 180, 90  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :   1.2 
#max value   :   7.1 
xmin(r)
#[1] -180
t <- r          # duplication
xmin(t) <- -300 # xmin modification of the duplicated SpatRaster
xmin(r)         # the original SpatRaster has also been modified
#[1] -300
```

Is it an error or a choice? It only occurs for some attributes, not all. If it is a choice, what is the way to create an 'independant" copy, or how to break the link?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because a SpatRaster is just a wrapper around a C++ object. That makes `x` (below) a shallow copy (i.e. pointing to the same object in memory)

```
library(terra)
r <- rast()
x <- r
```

It only matters in some cases, when using replacement methods (your example is no longer affected with current `terra`). I have also added a `copy` method that returns a deep copy, that is, a SpatRaster pointing to a different (deep copied) C++ object.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear. You are wright, keeping such side effects could be puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

For information, function `add` has the same problem (in `terra` 1.0.11):

```
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
nlyr(logo)
[1] 3
 
r <- logo
 
add(r) <- r[[1]]

nlyr(logo)
#[1] 4
```

Comment: This is intentional  ---- and a rather different case.

Comment: Thanks. What is the intent of this behaviour, in the case of the function `add`?

Comment: Users cannot know in advance which functions will cause such side effects and which will not.  It should be explained somewhere. Otherwise, one cannot write reliable scripts. 

Or it should be stated that one should never make simple raster assignments, but always hard copies?

Comment: `function(x) <- value` always changes `x` --- so the behavor of `add` should be as expected. What else could you expect to happen? .

Answer (score 0):

There may be a misunderstanding here, especially from me. The fact that `add(r) <- r[[1]]` changes `r` is absolutely normal, as you point out. But the fact that it also changes `logo` is not at all routine (the `add` function is supposed to add a layer to `r`, not to any other object unrelated to the current script line, according to the documentation).

If I understood correctly, and as you explained before, it is because `r <- logo` doesn't duplicate `logo` (deep copy) but only creates a pointer (shallow copy) to `logo`. This choice has important consequences on the use of `terra` objects since later modifications of `r` will also modify the `logo` object (a "side effect", from the user's point of view). I see at least 3 points here:

1. Unusual behaviour. Perhaps the user should be warned.

"In R semantics, objects are copied by value. This means that modifying the copy leaves the original object intact.": deep or lazy copies are a basic rule of R (https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/duplicate.html). The user must therefore be well aware that simple assignments in `terra` (`r <- logo`) do not copy by value, but by reference, otherwise the risk of error in the scripts is high. However, this unusual behavior is currently not explained in the documentation of `terra`.

2. Shallow copies are more a programmer-oriented tool.

When users will undersand that `terra` copies are shallow copies, they will probably most often prefer to make deep copies, because the use of shallow copies for `terra` users is probably restricted and uncommon. I don't see too many cases where this behaviour would be useful. Deep or lazy copies are much more common for users.

3. Heterogeneous behaviour according to functions

But that's not the main question. The main problem in the fact that, for the moment, some operations affect both the original object and the copied object, and others don't. `add` modifies the original object (side effect), but `res` doesn't change it :

```
logo <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))
nlyr(logo)
# [1] 3
res(logo)
# [1] 1 1

r <- logo

add(r) <- r[[1]]
nlyr(logo)
# side effect of add function on the number of layers
# [1] 4
res(r) <- c(10,10)
res(logo)
# no side effect of res function on the resolution
# [1] 1 1
```

If all these conjectures are right, it would be useful to explain which functions, after an assignment, do or do not affect the original object, otherwise one cannot program reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent clarificaiton --- although it may may more sense to edit your question, so that I can aswer it properly. But I will try here: `res` returns a new object and avoids the shallow copy problem. It can easily do that. `add` does not make a deep copy because that is very expensive, and the reason for having add is to allow efficient adding of layers. However, I may change the default so that it makes a deep copy unless told not to.

Comment: I understand. As this is a deliberate choice to improve the efficiency of `terra`, it seems to me necessary for programming reliability to list, in the `terra:copy` help page, the exact list of functions and `terra` operators that work by reference. One of the other (infrequent) packages that have made this choice is `data.table`. The help page of `data.table::copy` clearly indicates that the functions `data.table::set` and the `:=` operator are the only cases where no hard copy is made. It is difficult to write reliable `terra` scripts without this information.